# Logging in to a site and loading some pages

Tags: php, html

I know how to load a page from another website and analyze it but the website I'm trying to load some pages from, doesn't let unregistered users to visit those pages. I do have a username and a password to load those pages normally in my browser, but I'm wondering if I could do it in PHP or not? :/
I'm not sure what information I should give you about the website but if what I already told is incomplete just ask what information I should give.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to crawl that website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most websites use [cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) to store information related to your authentication status. 
To get past this programatically, you'll have to send this information everytime you make a request. Here is how you can get it -

- Using a tool like [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), inspect the cookies the site sends when you login manually.
- Write code to capture this information and send this cookie with subsequent requests

Note: Do check the [ToS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terms_of_service) of the site you are trying to [scrape](https://duckduckgo.com/Web_scraping). Some sites do not permit you to scrape or use their content without prior permission

Answer (score 0):

Research php SOAP. It includes the tools to log in to another site, giving your php script access to the HTML which would normally be presented to the browser. BTW, this is called *scraping*